explaning class/profile membership in a latent profile analyses
I have two variables V1 and V2 that I would like to use in determining the number of optimal profiles using the LPA package in R. Is it possible to include other predictor variables (e.g. age, education, height, etc.)  also in the LPA package to explain class/profile membership.Is it possible to do this in a one-stage process unlike first determining the number of optimal profiles and later predicting profile membership? I am using the mclust package.
